# CSS Navigation Bar Bug

Tags: css

How to remove the space shown here?

[image]

Hi , I have a CSS Bug on my code, the problem is shown in the picture. an extra space is outputing.
I copied this code from google. i wasted a lot of time to find that but nothing came good.

Here is my HTML code

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
                        <ul>

                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>

                        </ul>


                        </li>
                        </ul>


                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and the CSS is

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }


nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 

    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }

        nav ul li a {
            display: block; padding:5px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


    nav ul ul {

        position: absolute; top: 100%;
    }
        nav ul ul li {

            float: none;position: relative;
        }

    nav ul ul ul {
        position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove both padding and margin for the ul element. for example with this:

```
nav ul ul { margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;}
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34Fh7/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use css universal selector selector `*`:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ej7K/1/)

Take a look here [Universal Selector](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/universal-selector-css-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

i remove

`padding:5px;`  from   `nav ul li a`

and add

`padding: 0 10px;` for  `nav ul li a`

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/rqELv/